# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library

Tags: java, dll, jar

```
DLL INSTANCE = (DLL) Native.loadLibrary(Settings.getSingletonInstance().getProperty("default.ergoPointer.path"), DLL.class);
```

I store the dll path in settings file. When i take output of

```
Settings.getSingletonInstance().getProperty("default.ergoPointer.path"
```

here : `C:\Users\Argenit\Desktop\aaa\dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit.dll`

Error part :

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library
>   'C:\Users\Argenit\Desktop\aaa\dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit.dll': Native
>   library
>   (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\Argenit\Desktop\aaa\dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit.dll)
>   not found in resource path
>   ([file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/bin/,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/resources/,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/fits.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/json.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/kdu_jni.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/JNA/jna-4.1.0.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/JNA/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/ini4j-0.5.4.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/JNA/,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/gluegen-rt.jar,
>   file:/C:/Users/Argenit/Desktop/Pathology_JAVA/Digital_Pathology/lib/jogl.jar])

If i add (dll) as a external class folder in project and write : `loadLibrary("ErgoPointer_64_Bit")`, it works in this machine but when i take the runnable jar, it couldn' t find `ErgoPointer_64_Bit` so i want to give absolute path of dll. But it doesn' t work for me.

I also tried :

> C:\Users\Argenit\Desktop\aaa\dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit
>
> dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit
>
> ErgoPointer_64_Bit
>
> dll\ErgoPointer_64_Bit.dll
>
> ErgoPointer_64_Bit.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the system property java.library.path before the call Native.loadLibrary() with just the base name.

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", 
            "C:\\Users\\Argenit\\Desktop\\aaa\\dll;" 
              + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
DLL INSTANCE = (DLL) Native.loadLibrary("ErgoPointer_64_Bit", DLL.class);
```

You can also set the java.library.path on the command line. eg.

```
java "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Argenit\Desktop\aaa\dll\" -jar somejar.jar
```

Comment: how can i know computer name (Argenit) in different computers ?

Comment: You can get the computer name with `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` but actually Argenit looks like the user name not the host name. You can get the user's home directory with `System.getProperty("user.home")` or just the user's name with `System.getProperty("user.name")`.

Comment: thanks a lot, and i found the mistake. the os is 64 bit but java is 32 bit. i export 64 bit dll, so that why it didnt work