# Jna path resolving

Tags: java, eclipse, jna

Im trying to use GStreamer in eclipse via jna.
Processing provides a library for that and all is fine if i try to run the code by running the sketch as an applet from eclipse, but when i try to execute the whole application i get a list of warnings(on Camera first call) like this one

(javaw.exe:3840): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll': `C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll': Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.

on 30+ of 140 plugins (probably the ones needed by my library for the camera managment)

the jna jar and the libraries are in the project folder C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/
and included in the build path

and the native code is in C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/windows64/plugins/

the path doesnt seem correct...

i never wrote libraries that need jna and i was trying to use this library as is if possible, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988071/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-unable-to-load-library

Comment: C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll would be correct C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll probably is not

Comment: You might try tweaking the gstreamer configuration to change the plugin path to be "windows64/plugins/" instead of "\windows64\plugins\".  I'm not sure how the underlying file/path resolution works when it finds "/\" as a path separator.

Comment: thank you, i too was highly suspicious about that path but apparenty running a main that instantiate the applet and adds it to a panel inside the view project(and then run as application) works, while doing the same from the root project doesnt work anymore, seems like some system property is dependant on witch project i launch the code but not knowing jna(and probably some basics) i cant figure out

Answer (score 0):

You can set the system property `jna.library.path` to the path to your primary library that is being loaded.  All of that library's dependencies must either be in that directory or on `%PATH%`.

You can find the dependent libraries using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: thanks for the answer i have tried System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/" ); System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\\windows64\\plugins\\" );and

Comment: thanks for the answer i have tried System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/" ); System.setProperty("jna.library.path","C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\\windows64\\plugins\\" );and ("jna.library.path","C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/windows64/plugins/" ); but no luck