# still stuck on jna path resolving

Tags: java, jna

im really having troubles figuring this out

Im trying to use GStreamer in eclipse via jna. Processing provides a library for that and all is fine if i try to run the code by running the sketch as an applet from eclipse, but when i try to execute the whole application i get a list of warnings(on Camera first call) like this one

```
(javaw.exe:3840): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll': `C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll': Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

on 30+ of 140 plugins (probably the ones needed by my library for the camera managment)

the jna jar and the libraries are in the project folder `C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/` and included in the build path

and the native code is in `C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/windows64/plugins/`

the path doesnt seem correct...

```
C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll'

C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/windows64/plugins/libgstvorbis.dll'
```

would be correct

i never wrote libraries that need jna and i was trying to use this library as is if possible, any suggestions?

Comment: how are you loading the libraries in you code ?

Comment: i added to the build path the jar that is supposed to reference them and jna platform jar. the C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/ part is dependent on the location of the linked library, while the \windows64\plugins\ is where the library search for plugins.dont know why the logic fails to resolve the path correctly while in processing IDE works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jna path resolving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313120/jna-path-resolving)

Comment: Please append any additional information to your original question, rather than posting several duplicate questions.

Comment: processing has some libraries witch are usefull to interact with some devices like camera and to do fast (codewise) elaboration of those inputs. some feature are not pure java and must depend on native language but i can afford that. of course the main feature of using library in the first place is to have some function at your disposal without knowing every aspect of what the implementation actually is. in my case im trying to use the very specific gstreamer processing 2.2.1 library to work in eclipse (outside the processing IDE where it works just fine).

Comment: im experiencing this (strange?) issue regarding path resolving. Being able to call c code from java seems a big topic to me and one on witch im ignorant. from my point of view a famous library should work ez. .i dont even know if the path C:/Users/aaa/Desktop/bbb/ccc/video/library/\windows64\plugins\libgstvorbis.dll (notice the /\ in the library location) could be correct